# How should I convert a bool to a numeric value (int or decimal) with Linq to entities?

Tags: c#, casting, linq-to-entities

I'm joining against a set {uniqueidentifier ID, bool IsRead).  I want to compute a readership rate, so I'm doing this:

```
inbox.GroupJoin(
    isRead,
    p => p.ID,
    r => r.ID,
    (p, r) => new {ID = p.ID, ReadRate = r.Sum( x => x.IsRead ) / (decimal)r.Count() }
)
```

That doesn't compile because it cannot sum a Boolean.  I need to convert the IsRead property to a decimal for the Sum function, but I'm concerned about the performance of the cast method used.

- I could use `x => x.IsRead ? 1 : 0` right in the Sum call, but I don't think a conditional is appropriate.
- `x => Convert.ToDecimal` isn't recognized by Linq2Entities (`Convert.*` in general isn't supported from what I understand).
- Direct cast with `(int)` doesn't work on a Boolean in C#.
- `r.Cast<decimal>()` won't work, because it doesn't have a selector like `Sum`, so I cannot select the `IsRead` property from the object without additional work.
- I could use `r.Select( x => x.IsRead ).Cast<decimal>().Sum()`, but do I really need that Select?
- I could convert the Boolean to an integer sooner, but I'm not sure how to do that at the point of assignment in an earlier join where it looks like `(a,b) => new {ID = a.ID, IsRead = b.IsRead}`.

Answer (score 1):

May be it will solve your problem: Change

```
r.Sum( x => x.IsRead )
```

to

```
r.Count( x => x.IsRead )
```